# Visual Studio Code Extension - npm installation failed becuase of package dependency?

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code, npm-install

I'm trying to write a small extention for Visual Studio Code but it fails right at the beginning.

I installed yo, as intended

`npm install -g yo generator-code`

however, now when I'm trying to start everything up, I get errors.

I created a project using `yo code` and following the generator. I tried Extension Typescript and Javascript, both failed.

the settings used:

- initialize a git repository: yes
- package manager: npm

> Running npm install for you to install the required
>   dependencies. If this fails, try running the command yourself.

The auto installation failed, running `npm install` however caused the same error:

```
npm WARN registry Unexpected warning for https://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning EPROTO: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/mocha failed, reason: write EPROTO 10300:error:14094417:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert illegal parameter:c:\\ws\\deps\\openssl\\openssl\\ssl\\record\\rec_layer_s3.c:1407:SSL alert number 47\n
npm WARN registry Using stale data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @types/vscode@^1.43.0.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'smartfilesnfolders'
npm ERR! notarget

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\lechn\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-03-10T12_50_32_409Z-debug.log
```

full log: https://gist.github.com/lechnerio/e1356b2edb48cbdedf40fd1570267bb7

thankful for any hints and tips. npm and vscode are up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the same error a moment ago. I solved it by changing `@types/vscode` version to `^1.42.0` in `package.json`.

Comment: Thank you very much Konstantin. Worked without issue.